# Worker doesn't consume task when using apply_async() in celery

Tags: python, queue, celery

I'm trying to use celery outside of django project.
i define a task like this :

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks')
app.conf.update(
    result_backend="rpc",
    broker_url="redis://localhost:6379/0",

    task_soft_time_limit=2,
    task_time_limit=10,
    task_create_missing_queues=True,

    task_log_format='[%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s/%(processName)s] %(message)s',
    task_log_datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',

    worker_redirect_stdouts=True,
    worker_redirect_stdouts_level='INFO',
    worker_prefetch_multiplier=10,
)


@app.task()
def print_hi():
    print("hi")
```

and start the worker like this :

```
celery -A some_task worker --loglevel=INFO --without-gossip
```

and then add some tasks to the queue like this :

```
from some_task import print_hi

print_hi.apply_async(queue="queue")
```

my problem is that the worker instance is not consuming the task that I'm adding to the queue, I monitored `redis` and made sure the enqueuing process is done correctly. also when i use `delay()`, the workers consumes task like normal but when using `apply_async()` nothing happens

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical Celery mistake... - What is going on is obvious. You are sending task to a queue, but you do not have worker(s) subscribed to that queue.

If you want `print_hi.apply_async(queue="anthrax")` to work, you need to run Celery worker with: `celery -A some_task worker -Q anthrax --loglevel=INFO --without-gossip`